# Does SQLiteDatabase.insert() prevent SQL injection attacks?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've checked the documentation, but I didn't see it address SQL injections. Does the insert() method automatically prevent injections, or must they be prevented manually? Thanks.

Comment: I think `insert()` is safe. It's parameterized at least. I don't see how injection is possible with it. But don't take my word for it.

Comment: That's what I imagined, but it would be more reassuring to find some confirmation one way or another, especially when dealing with vulnerabilities.

Comment: If in doubt you can check out the Android source code. Calling insert does create a parameterized query with questionmark placeholders (see SQLIteDatabase.java -> insertWithOnConflict), so yes it should be safe.

Comment: Thanks @NobuGames. I'll give the source a read through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android API calls SQLite native library to bind parameters. So, assuming the prepared statements are correctly written, queries are safe.

Relevant source code:

- [SQLiteConnection.bindArgument()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConnection.java#SQLiteConnection.bindArguments%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.PreparedStatement%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)
- [nativeBindString()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android_database_SQLiteConnection.cpp#L398)